# Class added to My namespace not available on MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, namespaces

I have the following class added to the My namespace in a .NET 3.5 MVC2 VB app:

```
Namespace My

    Public Class Environment

        Public Shared ReadOnly Property IsProduction As Boolean
            ...code here...
        End Property

    End Class

End Namespace
```

I've used it throughout the app, but I can't reference it directly on a view. For example, this code flags "My.Environment" and says it's not a member of "My":

```
<p>
    Are you are in production? <%= My.Environment.IsProduction %>
</p>
```

Is there an extra step that needs to be done for the view to see my additions to the My namespace?

Comment: Your class Environment is not a static class and so, in order to access its members you need an instance of it. The way you're using it is asif it's a static class and it's not.

Comment: Not if I'm accessing a Shared property. I can call "If My.Environment.IsProduction Then ..." in a controller or other class with no instance of Environment necessary.

Comment: I forgot that VB.NET uses Shared rather than static. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code again, Jamie is right. You have to instantiate the class before using it in a view. Assuming you are passing the instantiated variable, say, environment to model, you can do this:

```
<p>
Are you are in production? <%= model.IsProduction %>
</p>
```

Comment: See response to Jamie's comment - property is Shared, so instance necessary.

Comment: Yeah, but in View, you cannot access everything. Actually that's purpose of MVC. You can only access model in view. Of course, you can access ViewData/ViewBag but in order to access a specific method, you may want to use HtmlHelper extension.

Comment: You're right. Forgot about that. Thanks for the thorough explanation.